# Unable to get accessToken via Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, gatsby

Trying to get the access token from my first axios call and place it into the 2nd. My component is like so.

When i log `accessToken` to the console its an empty array. When i `console.log(response.data)` I can see the response and my `access_token`

```
const Route = (props) => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState([]);
  const [route, setRoute] = useState([]);
  const [athlete, setAthlete] = useState([]);

  // get a refreshed token from strava
  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
      params: {
        client_id: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_REFRESH_TOKEN,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setAccessToken(response.data.access_token);

        console.log(accessToken);

        return axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/routes/${props.data.contentfulRoutes.slug}`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        });
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setRoute(response.data);
        setAthlete(response.data.athlete);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're keeping the token in the state, and once you update the state in the middle of the function, the value is not updated synchronously, thus you're still getting an empty array. I would rephrase your `useEffect` with an `async/await` syntax like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
        try {
            const firstResponse = await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
                params: {
                    client_id: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                    refresh_token: process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                },
            })
            const token = firstResponse.data.access_token;
            setAccessToken(token) // Keep this line only if you need the token for something else later
            const secondResponse = await axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/routes/${props.data.contentfulRoutes.slug}`,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
            });

            console.log(secondResponse.data);
            setRoute(secondResponse.data);
            setAthlete(secondResponse.data.athlete);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    init();
}, []);
```

And then you can get rid of your `accessToken` state, it's redundant and not going to serve you well here (unless you need to keep it for something else, in which case you can keep the line I commented on)